# Change exec-maven-plugin Version for NetBeans Maven Java Project

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-3

When I run a Java Maven project in NetBeans, Maven first executes the following plugin:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Questionnaire ---
```

How can I change the plugin version that is executed? I would instead like to use version 1.1.1.

I have tried specifying the version in the `<build>` section of the pom, as follows, to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>My Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that I can change the *Execute Goals* for the *Run Project* Action in the project properties of the run configuration.

[image]

Comment: In order to always have the same version as with maven command line, I removed the version `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec` and put it in `<pluginManagement>` (see answer by khmarbaise).

Answer (score 4):

The best is to defined the version of the appropriate plugin within a pluginManagement section in your pom file and not within your IDE.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ..
  </build>
   ..
</project>
```

Comment: Indeed, Netbeans uses the version set in `<pluginManagement>`, if you remove the version from nbactions.xml like this: `<goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec</goal>`.